# Komascript scrlttr2: how to change name in signature?

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

StackExchange-Members,

I am using  scrlttr2`. For some reasons I would like to have a different name in the address line than in the signature.

For example:

> Merlin A. Etzold
>   00 SomeRoad
>   Some Town
>   ST1 SP1

as address... and

> Merlin Etzold

as signature. This is a problem which may also be faced by those living in the Germanic speaking countries (particularly Austria) who want to put a name prefix (such as Dipl.-Ing.) in the address but not in the signature...

Thank you and best wishes,
Merlin :)

Comment: I think you can use `setkomavar` multiple times?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The signature is saved in the variable `signature`. Default is `\usekomavar{fromname}`.

```
    \documentclass{scrlttr2}

    \setkomavar{fromname}{Merlin the wizard}
    \setkomavar{signature}{Merlin, the master of desaster}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{Ozzy, the metal wizard}
    \opening{Dear friend}
    some awesome text here.
    \closing{Best wishes}
    \end{letter}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: `Merlin, the master of desaster`? +1 :)